# Do threads really do things in Parallel?

Tags: multithreading

I need to know some thing about threads. I was writing an small crawler in Java and I will be starting with an URL, add the outgoing URLs to a database and crawl the next one (not multithreaded).

My project will eventually have to be multithreaded.

I have some doubts. When using threads we use a lock on a function so that only one thread should use that function. Is multithreading still useful then?

Answer (score 2):

Threading is useful, especially if your process is truly parallelizable and you have multiple cores available to you.

Threads are time-sliced by the operating system if you only have one CPU.  So if you have many tasks that are similar in nature, you might find that starting them all off at the same time won't result in a noticable performance improvement, because all they'll do is context switch.  (The resources needed to do the context switching might actually worsen performance.)

You can make your app seem more responsive if you have a long-running process (e.g. a file I/O process or calculation).  You can have one thread do that task while allowing the main or user thread return so clients can continue to do work rather than wait.

Answer (score 0):

> is multi threading is usefull....

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

In the time when processors had only one core, the multithreading was meaning pseudo parallelism. So, some time processor executes one thread, some another. Now, there are multiprocessor system and processors with double and quad cores. So there real multitasking is available.